# time complexity for this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i *= 2)
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        sum++;
```

I think it's time complexity is O(n) (1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 ... = (1(2^(log2n)-1))/(2-1), **sum of geometric sequence**). Is it right? I'm confused with my answser.

Comment: `log(n) * (log(n) + 1) / 2` according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5E%7Blog%28n%29%7Di)... Which is basically `O(log(n) ^ 2)`.

Comment: `i` grows by being *2 at each iteration, thus the number of iterations will be much smaller than `n`,  log2(n) actually. Then the `j` loop will do 1, then 2... or 1+2+...+log2(n) iterations, meaning O(log2(n)^2) = `O(log(n)^2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` changes in these steps: `1, 2, 2^2, ..., 2^log(n)` and in each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop run `i` times. Hence, the time complexity `T(n)` is `1 + 2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^log(n)` which is equal to `2^{log(n) + 1} -1`. Threfore, `T(n) = Theta(n)`.